# Call post API from-data body using MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, multipartform-data, form-data

How to call post API that using form-data in body message by using MVC client-side.

The API body has TWO attributes in form-data that is message another one is attachments:

[image]

I have tried a few methods but its return error due to malformed. This is my code:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        string APIUrl = "https://mynewuploadapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/customers/discount";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkzMzYyMTYwLCJpc3MiOiJQbHVzbWlsZXNBUEkifQ.DC42fI7dmKCTwzXPyrI5vs6Sxp0FMrOgvvr_uECzJ7Q");
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mynewuploadapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/customers/discount");
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000000);
        
        var converter = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(model);
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("message", @converter),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("attachements", null)
        });

        var HTTPcontent = new StringContent(@converter, Encoding.UTF8, "multipart/form-data");

        var response = await client.PostAsync(APIUrl, HTTPcontent);
```

and its worked on postman as the screenshot below:
[image]

This is another try on my controller which is also return code:500

```
#region New Try 26Jun
        var newclient = new HttpClient();
        newclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkzMzYyMTYwLCJpc3MiOiJQbHVzbWlsZXNBUEkifQ.DC42fI7dmKCTwzXPyrI5vs6Sxp0FMrOgvvr_uECzJ7Q");
        newclient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000000);
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "message", jsonDeserilizeFromModel},
            { "attachements", null }
        };
        var values = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
        var newresponse = await newclient.PostAsync(APIUrl, values);
        newresponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        #endregion
```

Details postman call below:
URL - `https://mynewuploadapi. azurewebsites.com/api/v1/customers/discount`

Header:
Authorization : `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkzNDIzNzg2LCJpc3MiOiJQbHVzbWlsZXNBUEkifQ.MWa-pbYneOUKvO0_dVVXVFENwBrpU3eGWc47j1YpcmQ`

Body. Method (form-post)
message:

```
 {
  "tx_type": "Kad Perjalanan",
  "applicant_type": "Pekerja/Pelajar",
  "reg_type": "Permohonan Baharu",
  "ic_type": "NRIC",
  "ic_no": "821210-10-1010",
  "title": "Encik",
  "ic_name": "Ali",
  "dob": "1982-12-10",
  "gender": "Lelaki / Male",
  "mailing_address": "",
  "state": "Selangor",
  "postcode": "40000",
  "city": "Subang",
  "email": "ali@plusti.my",
  "mobile_no": "01020202020",
  "v_make": "Proton",
  "v_model": "Saga",
  "v_year": "2009",
  "v_grant": "12345",
  "v_plateno": "BTP2021VC",
  "co_name": "PLUSTI",
  "co_address": "Tepi PLUSTI Highway",
  "co_postcode": "40000",
  "co_state": "Selangor",
  "co_phone": "0375525251",
  "tngcardno": "1234554321",
  "tngcard_expiry": null,
  "rfidtagno": null,
  "v_owner": "Y",
  "discount_type":"JPP"
}
```

Sample screenshot post-form body:
[image]

Anyone could please help me regarding this? Thank you

Comment: Are you able to show us the controller signature and the complete error message please?

Comment: the message on response result is error code 500.

Comment: postman doesn't sent the user name and password. Bearer JWT token in the header. same like what have in the source code too

Comment: @HoomanBahreini i just update my question with my code on controller

Comment: I was asking for controller code (server side) not client...

Comment: i see. i dont have access on the api source code. i can share the details on postman if u think it would able to help

Comment: If you can share the postman details, it would be good... it would help us to replicate the problem...

Comment: hi @HoomanBahreini i have updated my question with details for potman

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();
            string APIUrl = "https://localhost:44398/api/values/test1";
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000000);
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "message", "message" },
                { "attachements", null }
            };
            var values = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(APIUrl, values);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: I just updated my question, attached the postman success

Answer (score 0):

It is  worked:

```
  using (var response = await Task.Run(() => httpClient.PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, httpContent)))
                    {
                        var bodyString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            return new HttpResponseResult<T>()
                            {
                                StatusCode = response.StatusCode,
                                Body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(bodyString),
                                ContentType = response.Content.Headers.ContentType?.MediaType
                            };
                        }}
```

Answer (score 0):

this did the trick for me

```
 var baseUrl = "https://mynewuploadapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/customers/discount";
        var token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkzMzYyMTYwLCJpc3MiOiJQbHVzbWlsZXNBUEkifQ.DC42fI7dmKCTwzXPyrI5vs6Sxp0FMrOgvvr_uECzJ7Q";

        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
         
            using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                formData.Add(new JsonContent(message), "message");
                formData.Add(new JsonContent(fileContent), "attachements");

                httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000000);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(baseUrl, formData);
                if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    //ErrorEventArgs handling here
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is **misuse** of `HttpClient.BaseAddress` in your code. you must employ it like :

```
string APIUrl = "https://mynewuploadapi.azurewebsites.net/api/v1";
client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIUrl);

//then call api with the following
var response = await client.PostAsync("/customers/discount", content);
```

Second, depending on which way target api expects parameters to be sent him, you should figure out the request structure, Here you don't know about it unless trying to perform some tests. So let's focus on important parts of code :

**Authorization**

You employed right way to send authorization bearer which is:

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Your Oauth token");
```

**Data**

Your first try in order to *serialize* then *encoding* **twice** with `FormUrlEncodedContent` & `StringContent` looks **unusual**. Your second try suffers from using *jsonDeserilizeFromModel* as `string` in `Dictionary` while this is not the way to merge models. Based on expecting request form in target API, you can make use of one of the following solutions:

**Solution A** (when you can make a `Dictionary<string, string>` from the *model*):

```
MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
HttpContent file = new StringContent("file to upload as StreamContent");
HttpContent msgItems = new FormUrlEncodedContent(model.ToDictionary());//<string, string>
form.Add(file, "attachements");
form.Add(msgItems, "message");
var response = await client.PostAsync("/customers/discount", form);
```

**Solution B** create a new `model` (e.g `unitModel`) containing both *message* model and *attachements*:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(unitModel);// or JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize
var data = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await client.PostAsync("/customers/discount", data);
```

**Solution C** Post as Json :

```
//'unitModel' is a class containing both 'message' & 'attachements'
var result = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/customers/discount", unitModel);
```

We don't know which one can help you since *we can't reproduce your problem*. Considering that **any extra operation** such as *encoding* or *bundling the request body* **can be a reason for target API to return error**.